# Bootstrap: nav bar wont color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I got a problem with my bootstrap nav bar. It wont color the way I want it too and I tried adding code even with the `!import` but I can't get it to work

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-ligt fixed-top sticky-navigation " style="background: green !important;">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" style="background: green !important;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="ion-grid icon-sm"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand hero-heading" href="#">Jeroen Hooge</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#main">Product <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Werk</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#pricing">Prijs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This is what my code looks like but it won't color the background green only for the first milisecond or something.

[If I inspect the website you can see on the left that it somehow makes it a different color and I don't know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkcXF.png) There is nothing in the css making it that color. If I am on the top of the website it makes it transparent and if I scrol this color

Comment: change `background` to `background-color`

Comment: Doesnt matter it won't change either way @ZombieChowder

Comment: `"background: green !important;"` working for me !

Comment: May be other css is conflicting here,recheck all css by inspecting.

Comment: @Anuresh it isnt working for me.

Comment: Do u have a fiddle or site ?

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela it all links to the same css and there is nothing that makes it that color, not even in the css that are not even in use

Answer (score 0):

In head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Just before the closing of Body Tag

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Just check if you have added this correctly (or all the files).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check whether you are trying to change a css of already having !important

And already you are using the class bg-light which color your nav too. Remove it.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top sticky-navigation " style="background: green !important;">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" style="background: green !important;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="ion-grid icon-sm"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand hero-heading" href="#">Jeroen Hooge</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#main">Product <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Werk</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#pricing">Prijs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```